# publish packages in conda forge receive error 'MY PACKAGE requires pathlib, which is not installed'

Tags: python-3.x, package, pypi, pathlib, conda-forge

This is quite strange as `pathlib` seems already built in `python > 3.4`, anyone got an idea what raises the error? 
ps. Package is already in pypi, the recipe was created directly from `grayskull`.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with another package; during the conda-forge tests, the docker build is installing `pytables` as the recipe requires, but then the test fails, saying that `pytables is not installed`. 

(log: https://dev.azure.com/conda-forge/feedstock-builds/_build/results?buildId=486001&view=logs&j=656edd35-690f-5c53-9ba3-09c10d0bea97&t=e5c8ab1d-8ff9-5cae-b332-e15ae582ed2d )