# "[lib] requires [dep], which is not installed" when running PR tests on conda-forge feedstock, despite explicit call in grayskull-generated meta.yaml

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, conda, pytables, conda-forge

I'm trying to upgrade the conda-forge version of `xagg` to the latest version (v0.3.0). The built-in Azure Pipelines tests that run when I set up a PR of the feedstock into the conda-forge repository however fail, with the error:

```
import: 'xagg'
import: 'xagg'
+ pip check
xagg 0.3.0 requires pytables, which is not installed.
```

(the full log is [here](https://dev.azure.com/conda-forge/feedstock-builds/_build/results?buildId=486001&view=logs&j=656edd35-690f-5c53-9ba3-09c10d0bea97&t=e5c8ab1d-8ff9-5cae-b332-e15ae582ed2d))

The odd thing is that `pytables` is explicitly mentioned in the `meta.yaml` (which was generated through `grayskull` and is listed in the PR changes [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/xagg-feedstock/pull/11/files#diff-f3725a55bf339595bf865fec73bda8ac99f283b0810c205442021f29c06eea9a)), and, at least according to the test log, was correctly installed into the test docker environment:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

[snip]

pytables:                  3.7.0-py310hf5df6ce_0             conda-forge

[snip]

DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/linux-64/pytables-3.7.0-py310hf5df6ce_0.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4914957

[snip]

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to troubleshoot this? The [suggestions](https://github.com/conda-forge/tqdm-feedstock/issues/104) I've seen so far are to explicitly list the dependency in the `meta.yaml`, which I have.

I believe this may be a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339524/publish-packages-in-conda-forge-receive-error-my-package-requires-pathlib-whic), though for an optional package, not a built-in one.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Why was the dependency in `setup.py` changed to `pytables`? That isn't a PyPI package. In Conda `meta.yaml`, it should by `pytables`, but in the actual package `setup.py` it should just be `tables`.

Comment: Ah, interesting - so I just reuploaded / tried again with `pytables` changed to `tables` in `setup.py`, and the tests work now! Thank you a ton (I'll make this an accepted answer if you'd like to make it one, for the stackoverflow credit) 

So is what you're saying that `setup.py` ends up just getting used by `pypi`, but can pass the pypi dev checks in GitHub actions, but that the conda-forge dev checks need all the things in `setup.py` to be available on `pypi` (which is then tested separately from the `meta.yaml` recipe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conda recipe looks fine. It's actually the upstream package that was broken, as indicated by the failure of `pip check`.

Namely, `pip check` ensures that the packages listed as dependencies in the `setup.py` are all installed. However, the v3.0.0 release lists a `pytables` package, which is not a valid PyPI package. Instead, this should have been simply `tables`.

Perhaps, this confusion arose because in the Conda ecosystem the Python package `tables` goes by the name `pytables`. This is simply part of the issue with having a generic package manager - packages across language ecosystems have namespace collisions, and therefore get renamed with a prefix or some other modifier (e.g., all CRAN packages have `r-` prefixed). So, in the Conda recipe one indicates the Conda package name (`pytables`), but `pip check` will verify that this actually makes the `tables` module available.

Comment: Thank you - that makes a lot of sense!